# Windows configuration to registers

Tags: emacs

I'm starting to use quite heavily the commands C-x r w and C-x r j to store windows configuration to registers and recall them at a later point, but I find a bit annoying that the cursor positions are stored as per the time when the window configuration was saved.

Basically I would like that the cursor positions are not stored (or are updated automatically), so that whenever I "jump" to a stored window configuration I get the same view as when I last visited it, not as when I created it.

Any ideas?
Ángel

Answer (score 4):

I also found this very annoying and just coded up a solution. Store the window config using the normal functionality (current-window-configuration or window-configuration-to-register). Then, before applying the saved window config (or register),

- Store the points of all open buffers.
- Restore the window config.
- Apply the stored points to the current windows.

The code below does this. You'll have to hook up restore-window-configuration to the register code yourself though.

```
(defun buffer-point-map ()
  (save-excursion
    (mapcar (lambda (buffer) (cons (buffer-name buffer)
                                   (progn (set-buffer buffer) (point))))
            (buffer-list))))

(defun apply-buffer-points (buff-point-map)
  (mapc (lambda (window) (let* ((buffer (window-buffer window))
                                (buffer-point (cdr (assoc (buffer-name buffer) buff-point-map))))
                           (when buffer-point (set-window-point window buffer-point))))
        (window-list))
  nil)

(defun restore-window-configuration (window-config)
  (let ((points (buffer-point-map)))
    (set-window-configuration window-config)
    (apply-buffer-points points)))
```

Answer (score 3):

If you take a look into a source code

```
(defun window-configuration-to-register (register &optional arg)
  ...
  (set-register register (list (current-window-configuration) (point-marker))))
```

you'll see that it stores a point as the second argument. 
Just re-define it like

```
(defun my-window-configuration-to-register (register &optional arg)
  (interactive "cWindow configuration to register: \nP")
  (set-register register (list (current-window-configuration) nil)))
```

and redefine a C-x r w shortcut as well to use  `my-window-configuration-to-register`

```
(define-key (current-global-map) (kbd "C-x r w") 'my-window-configuration-to-register)
```

Or define an advice

```
(defadvice window-configuration-to-register (after window-configuration-to-register-no-point activate)
  "Avoid storing current buffer's position in the register. We want to stay on the last used position, not to jump to the saved one"
  (set-register register (list (current-window-configuration) nil)))
```

The only problem is that it brings up an error message when you jump to it. You may redefine `jump-to-register` to avoid it

Comment: Hi, that's great, but I was hoping there would be some option in the stock Emacs (since I use it in a number of computers, and I would prefer not to write code for each of them)

Comment: Well, as it looks in the source code they is no such option. From my experience I customize Emacs a lot, one more customization does not change anything

Comment: OK, so I added new my-window-configuration-to-register and my-jump-to-register definitions to my .emacs file and it works perfectly now. Thanks a lot

Comment: sorry, spoke too early... So far I can only avoid restoring the points at creation of the current buffer for each window configuration. The points for the other buffers are given (and restored) by current-window-configuration and set-window-configuration which are C functions and I don't see an easy way of manipulating them from within Emacs...

Comment: I would recommend that you try to avoid redefining functions whenever possible. A better approach is to use `advice`, which lets you manipulate the execution of any function or macro regardless of whether it is written in elisp or C. http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/elisp/html_node/Advising-Functions.html

Comment: thanks, I looked into the advice thing. My hope was that I could just change the set-window-configuration function so that the stored point is just not used, but I still have to see how to interact with the C function properly. If I manage to do it I will report back.

Answer (score 1):

I'll add another answer which uses different approach.

Before you jump to another register you may store the current window configuration. This way it will store your latest buffers position just before you jump.

This will not work in all cases, however. For example if you just switch to another buffer or create a buffer with `M-x dired` or something then it will not store the current window config.

```
(defvar current-window-conf-register nil)

(defadvice window-configuration-to-register (after window-configuration-to-register-current-reg activate)
  (setq current-window-conf-register register))

(defadvice jump-to-register (before jump-to-register-store-window-conf activate)
  (if current-window-conf-register (window-configuration-to-register current-window-conf-register))
  (setq current-window-conf-register register))
```

Answer (score 0):

As a indirect answer to your question, you might consider using `revive.el` instead, which supports saving and restoring window configurations across Emacs restart, but doesn't (I believe) store the point.

Comment: thanks, I will check it again, but last time I looked I think it didn't suit me very well, either because it also stored the point or because I couldn't save different configurations and name them for recalling them later.